# Vagrant Rackspace HTTP 413 Personality file content too long

Tags: ssh, vagrant, rackspace-cloud

### Works without custom SSH-keypair

Trying to get going with Vagrant and Rackspace, I was able to spool up a box with the dummy *.box* file and insecure Vagrant keys, following [these instructions](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace#quick-start).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  #----------
  # config.vm
  #----------
  config.vm.box     = "dummy"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace/raw/master/dummy.box"

  #------------------
  # config rackspace
  #------------------
  config.vm.provider :rackspace do |rs|
    rs.username         = "xxxxxx"
    rs.api_key          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    rs.flavor           = "1 GB Performance"
    rs.image            = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    rs.rackspace_region = "dfw"
    rs.server_name      = "test-vagrant"
  end
end
```

### Broken with custom SSH-keypair

Trying to then specify a keypair with the following configuration

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  #----------
  # config.vm
  #----------
  config.vm.box     = "dummy"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace/raw/master/dummy.box"

  #-----------
  # config.ssh
  #-----------
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "/Users/natedogg/.ssh/id_rsa"

  #------------------
  # config rackspace
  #------------------
  config.vm.provider :rackspace do |rs|
    rs.username         = "xxxxxx"
    rs.api_key          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    rs.flavor           = "1 GB Performance"
    rs.image            = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    rs.rackspace_region = "dfw"
    rs.server_name      = "test-vagrant"
    rs.public_key_path  = "/Users/natedogg/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  end
end
```

`vagrant up --provider=rackspace` results in an HTTP 413 from Rackspace.

> ~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in
>   `response_call': [HTTP 413 | ] Personality file content too long
>   (Fog::Compute::RackspaceV2::ServiceError)

### Have Tried

- Different `rs.flavor` (`512MB Standard Instance`)
- Different installations of Vagrant

Comment: I noticed my SSH private key file is bigger than the default vagrant private key, maybe that's pushing some [create server](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/CreateServers.html) boundary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [maximum filesize](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/Server_Personality-d1e2543.html) that you're allowed to provide when you're injecting "personality" files onto a newly launched server, which you can find from the [limits endpoint](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/ProgrammaticLimits.html). Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to query that from Vagrant, but I'd expect that's what you're hitting. Mine is 1000 bytes!

What I'd recommend instead is to upload your public key as a named keypair -- which you can do through the web UI or [the API](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/ServersKeyPairs-d1e2545.html) -- and give Vagrant the keypair name:

```
config.vm.provider :rackspace do |rs|
  rs.username         = "xxxxxx"
  rs.api_key          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  rs.flavor           = "1 GB Performance"
  rs.image            = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  rs.rackspace_region = "dfw"
  rs.server_name      = "test-vagrant"
  rs.key_name         = "mykey"
end
```

Comment: Nice work my friend. I uploaded a public key and used `rs.key_name`, now working like a charm!